# How to solve 1-dimensional elastic collision using conservation of momentum and kinetic energy?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I'm building a 2-dimensional ball collision simulator, but I am stuck on how to do it in one dimension.  I am using the two equations and trying to generally solve for both final velocities.

(conservation of kinetic energy)

$$0.5m_1v_1^{2} + 0.5m_2v_2^2 = 0.5m_1v_1'^2 + 0.5m_2v_2'^2$$

(conservation of momentum)

$$m_1v_1 + m_2v_2 = m_1v_1' + m_2v_2'$$

I got pretty far along in solving for $v_2'$ but got to a point where I had $v_2'$ and $v_2'^2$ as terms on one side (unsolvable as far as I can do).  A full walkthrough on how to do the algebra for this would be appreciated, systems of equations have always been a challenge for me.

Comment: [See here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137835/elastic-collisions-and-conservation-of-momentum)

Comment: I need help walking through the algebra and that post is about inelastic collisions as far as I can tell.